# Reading the GUI in crystal reports

Tags: user-interface, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

On the bottom of crystal reports there is a "Records" number.

[image]

what exactly does this number mean? I couldn't find an explanation online

Comment: The number of records returned in the current run of your report.

Comment: Is that equal to the number of rows in a dataset or the number of cells?

Comment: Rows in the data set.